# Netbeans: Mode or interface change

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-8

I normally use NetBeans only for programming in Java, but some days ago a friend used my computer to show some UML on NetBeans. Now all the time NetBeans looks like this:

http://prntscr.com/9p2apk

And text editor became really weird and unconfortable.

Comment: Probably the easiest solution is to close Netbeans, delete the user config and cache directories (http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqWhatIsUserdir) and restart netbeans, that should reset Netbeans to its original settings.

Answer (score 0):

You can open any windows and panels which may have got closed by using the Windows menu and choosing the options for different panels in that menu.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I know that. The problem is that each time every time I start NetBeans again all the options and panels are gone, it always initialize in debugging mode

http://i.imgur.com/5VS5tHN.png

And the text editor changes a lot.

http://prntscr.com/9ph5rg

For example, I can't even use backspace to delete text.

Comment: Then I think it is time for you to clean the user directory as mentioned in the comment   by @WillShackleford to your question